# JMX vs VisualVM?

Tags: java, performance, monitoring, jmx, visualvm

I read couple of links about JMX and VisualVM, but still have a couple of questions around them.

As per my understanding, JMX & VisualVM are 2 different JVM monitoring tools. In-addition, JMX has APIs, which a java application could incorporate and allow the monitoring tools to better monitor the application.

Could someone clarify if this understanding is correct or flawed ? If flawed, could you please point to any articles explaining this difference/comparison better ?

Also, when do i go for using JMX or VisualVM to monitor my java based web application hosted on a Tomcat 6.1 server ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

That's not correct. `JConsole` & Java `VisualVM` are 2 different JVM monitoring tools. Java Management Extensions (JMX) is a Java technology that supplies tools for managing and monitoring applications, like `JConsole` or Java `VisualVM`

Comment: thank you for the clarification. So how do i decide between choosing JConsole vs. VisualVM for my monitoring purpose ? We have an application running in Tomcat 6.1 server.

Comment: Java VisualVM is a newer app with advanced monitoring features, eg profiling

Comment: JConsole uses only JMX, but VisualVM uses other monitoring technologies like Jvmstat, Attach API and SA in addition to JMX. It can merge data from all those monitoring technologies in one place and the user does not need to think which technology he should use in particular situation.

Comment: @TomasHurka : Thanks for the explanation. Saved the day.